# Loop content not displaying properly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a loop to run a number of times after the user enters a value into a textbox.

My program only displays the users character he entered once even though i have a loop which runs more than once.

Please have a look at my code:

```
<body>
<input type="text" Id="myValue"></input>&nbsp;
<button onclick="Display()">Display</button>
<p Id="Paragraph"></p>
<script>
function Display()
{   
   for(var i = 0; i < 4;  i++)
   {

     document.getElementById("Paragraph").innerHTML = "You entered:  " +  
     document.getElementById("myValue").value; 
   }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: you are simply overwriting the content of Paragraph

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  You're duplicating text for what reason?  Imagine I entered `hello` and clicked display: "You entered: helloYou entered: helloYou entered: helloYou entered: hello"

Comment: Why do you loop it...??

Comment: yeah no...I want to display the border of a square so i just used this example code to try and figure out how to do it. I replaced the "You Entered: " with " " so now only the characters will be displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the loop will iterate 4 times.But yor are replacing the value of textbox in each iteration.Thats what actually happens and you get the result of last iteration

If you want to check whether the loop executes 4 times or not 
Then write an alert() inside the loop

```
function Display()
{   
   for(var i = 0; i < 4;  i++)
   {
     alert(i);
     document.getElementById("Paragraph").innerHTML = "You entered:  " +  
     document.getElementById("myValue").value; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

make your inner code to this:

```
 document.getElementById("Paragraph").innerHTML += "You entered:  " +  
     document.getElementById("myValue").value;
```